# Line up list items in ionic and get a value

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic project that I'm working on and I'm using the columns in a grid that contains a static image on the top left (X) and a list of images on the right (Y).  What I would like to do is be able to scroll through the list on the right so when the X and Y images line up at the top it gives me the ID of the current Y image.

I am monitoring the scrolling, but I'm not sure how I should use it without it getting messy and making sure it works correctly on multiple devices.

These graphics give an idea of what I'm trying achive.  Anyone know how I can do this?  Thanks!

[image: Page Loaded]

[image: Scroll UP]

HTML Code

```
    <ion-content padding (ionScroll)="scrolling($event)" 
    (ionScrollEnd)="scrollComplete($event)">
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12>
        <div id="player" class="box">   
          <img class="profilePicture" src="../../assets/imgs/X.jpg"> 
          <ul>
              <li class="blue box ScoreBox">132<br /></li>
              <li class="blue box ScoreBox">243<br /></li>
              <li class="blue box ScoreBox">233<br /></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12>
      <ion-list *ngFor="let item of listItems;let i = index">
          <ion-item id="{{ i }}" *ngIf="i == 0">            
              <img src="../../assets/imgs/Y.jpg"  class="spacer">
          </ion-item>
        <ion-item id="{{ i }}" *ngIf="i > 0">            
            <img src="../../assets/imgs/Y.jpg">
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

TypeScript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-two-columns',
  templateUrl: 'two-columns.html',
})
export class TwoColumnsPage {
  listItems = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    // Generate the number of list items for testing
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      this.listItems.push( this.listItems.length );
    }
  }

  scrolling(event) {
    // your content here for scrolling
    console.log(event);
  }

  scrollComplete(event) {
   // your content here of scroll is finished
   console.log(event);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad TwoColumnsPage');
  }
}
```

Comment: I can not fully understand what you want to do. Can you explain it again with more details?

Comment: This will be hard to achieve using ion-grid. I would suggest ion-slides with option set to be vertical slides. With slides you have some control over active index etc